# Numerical Integration of Bessel K_0 and Hankel function.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, contour-integration, bessel-functions

I am trying to perform a numerical integration of a large integrand which includes the K_0 or the Hankel function as a part. I began with the study of behavior of K_0 and Hankel function alone and plotted the graphs and obtained the numerical values using mathematica and then python vegas package.
Now here is the problem, Mathematica and python give totally different results. I am not sure about any result or even my coding as I am not a mathematician. The mathematica code is as follows.

Hankel

```
In[32]:= Integrandh = HankelH1[0, Sqrt[D1h] b1]

Out[32]= HankelH1[0, b1 Sqrt[35.5614 + 19.2684 x1]]

Plot3D[Integrandh, {x1, 0.0001, 1}, {b1, 0.0001, 3.99}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x1", "b1", "Bessel[x1, b1]"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "3D Plot"]

In[46]:= f11 = NIntegrate[Integrandh, {x1, 0.1, .2}, {b1, 0.1, 3.99}]

Out[46]= 0.00407019 + 0.00884887 I
```

$K_0$ Bessel

$\text{Integrand}=K_0\left(\text{b1} \sqrt{\text{mD} \left(\text{mD}-\text{mB} \text{x1} \left(\eta +\sqrt{\eta ^2-1}\right)\right)}\right)$

$K_0\left(1.40321 \text{b1} \sqrt{1.969\, -9.78586 \text{x1}}\right)$

```
Plot3D[Integrand, {x1, 0.0001, 1}, {b1, 0.0001, 3.99}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}, AxesLabel -> {"x1", "b1", "Bessel[x1, b1]"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "3D Plot"]

In[45]:= f11 = NIntegrate[Integrand, {x1, 0.1, .3}, {b1, 0.1, 3.99}]

Out[45]= 0.142902 - 0.211705 I
```

I could not find the file attach option so I am copying the python code here.

```
import math
import vegas
from scipy.special import hankel1
import numpy as np

def integrand(x):
    x1, b1 = x
    return hankel1(0, b1 * np.sqrt(35.5614 + 19.2684 * x1))
    # return kv(0, 1.40321 * b1 * math.sqrt(1.969 - 9.78586 * x1))

# Define the integration range
x1_range = [0.0001, 1]
b1_range = [0.0001, 3.99]

# Define the vertical range
vertical_range = [0, 1.2]

# Set up the vegas integrator
integ = vegas.Integrator([x1_range, b1_range])

# Perform the integration
result = integ(integrand, nitn=10, neval=10000)

# Print the result
print(result.summary())
print("Estimated result: ", result.mean)
print("Standard error: ", result.sdev)
```

This is the output

[image]

Comment: could you paste your output of python?

Comment: @Yimin yes dear I have added the output.

Comment: Please note that in python you can comment/uncomment the relevant function to get output.

Comment: I see, your vegas library is using Monte Carlo to compute the integral, then the estimated result indeed will be a little different from the exact value due to the randomness, if you use a large nitn number, the value will be more accurate. I believe vegas has an implicit conversion from complex to real number, so you might want to split your input function into real and imaginary parts.